# LINQ Error in Simple Join - the type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to do a simple `JOIN` with `LINQ` but occurs the error

`the type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect`

**CODE:**

```
var select2 = from si in db.San_Imovel
                              join sic in db.San_Imovel_caracteristica      <--- ERROR 
                              on si.Imovel_Id equals sic.Imovel_Id
                             where si.Credenciada_Id == credenciada_Id                    
                             select new
                             {
                                 si.Celula_Id, 
                                 si.Credenciada_Id, 
                                 si.Imovel_Id,
                                 si.NomeArquivo, 
                                 si.TipoDsc1, 
                                 si.BairroDsc1,
                                 si.AreaRealPrivativa,                                  
                                 si.ValorImovel,
                                 si.ValorCondominio, 
                                 si.ValorIPTU, 
                                 si.Lat2, 
                                 si.Lon2,
                                 si.Bairro1, 
                                 si.NomeCidade,
                                 si.Transacao_ID
                             };
```

Comment: si.Imovel_Id & sic.Imovel_Id are of same type ?

Comment: What are the data types of si.Imovel_Id and sic.Imovel_Id? Please ensure that these two columns are of the same data type or you will get the error you are experiencing.

Comment: `long` and `int?` types. I'll convert the type and in a few minutes I can tell you if works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your properties have `long` and `int?` types, then you can try this join:

```
var select2 = from si in db.San_Imovel
              join sic in db.San_Imovel_caracteristica
                            .Where(x => x.Imovel_Id.HasValue)
              on si.Imovel_Id equals (long)sic.Imovel_Id.Value
              where si.Credenciada_Id == credenciada_Id                    
              select new { ... }
```